# how to scan barcode with square character on start and end of code quagga.js

Tags: javascript, barcode, quaggajs

I implemented a barcode reader functionality on my website with the Quagga.js javascript library which reads barcodes with a smartphone or computer camera, but the scanner does not convert barcodes that start and end with a rectangle character / symbol (some codes begin and end with a rectangle-like symbol). Is there something that I am not initializing or configuring well? Can someone help me please?  [image]

Answer (score 0):

That is a code93 barcode (not to be confused with code39).  It is fairly unusual in the real world and most barcode readers are not configured to read it by default.  Can you enable code93 in quagga.js?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mark Warren so I Will test It enabling code93 in the quagga.js. Hope It works.